# Sending POST data

Tags: post, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to connect with HTTP server and send some date. My code looks like ->

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.pl");
    string data = "Time = 12:00am temperature = 50";
    client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler    (UploadStringCallback2);
    client.UploadStringAsync(uri, data);
}

private static void UploadStringCallback2(Object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string reply = (string)e.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(reply);
}
```

I receive exception "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." My debug windows looks like

A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Please help!
PS: Ive got installed 7.1 SDK Beta but it should run on 7.0 emulator (Target windows phone verison is WP7).

**EDIT:**

Now code looks like

```
Uri uri = new Uri("MY SITE");
string data = "text=dupa";
//client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
headers[0] = " User-Agent: CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3";
client.Headers = headers;
client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(UploadStringCallback2);
client.UploadStringAsync(uri, data);
```

It connects to my PHP script

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]);
?>
```

But response is like

```
Array
(
)
NativeHost
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

**EDIT:**
OK, i figured it out ;) Everything is working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't accept a POST request. I don't know about WP7 but if you create a simple console app with the same code you get the exception that a post method's not allowed.

Comment: It helped a little :/ Now i receive response from my PHP script but POST and headers that i sent are empty :/ (I edited my question).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this class which simplifies HTTP calls: 
https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http (Link is to my codeplex project)

Usage:

```
var request = new PostRequest("http://myurl.ch");
request.Data.Add("name", "myname");
request.Data.Add("email", "myemail);
Http.Post(request, OnSendCompleted, Deployment.Current.Dispatcher);
```

`OnSendCompleted` is a method which is called after the HTTP call has finished. With this class it's also easy to send files.

Answer (score 0):

The WebClient class uses GET method internally, you gotta use the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes.
Here is a small snippet

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData = "parameter=value";
        // Getting the request stream.
        request.BeginGetRequestStream
            (result =>
                    {
                        // Sending the request.
                        using (var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                            {
                                writer.Write(postData);
                                writer.Flush();
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting the response.
                        request.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
                                                    {
                                                        var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
                                                        using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream() )
                                                        {
                                                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                                                            {
                                                                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                                                            }
                                                        }                                                         
                                                    }, null);
                    }, null);
```